# How to modify the attributes of a class in python using a method without returning the instance (inplace operation)

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance, scanpy

### Description of my goal and the problem:

I am currently working with the [scanpy](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [anndata](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/anndata.AnnData.html) packages in python (version 3.6.12). If you are not familiar with these packages, just know that the `anndata.AnnData` stores a data matrix (`numpy.ndarray`) in the attribue `X`. The columns of `X` are described in a `panda.DataFrame` in the `var` attribute and the rows are described in the `obs` attribute. See this [link](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/anndata.AnnData.html) for more information

My goal is to have a class (e.g. class A) that is inherited from the `anndata.AnnData` class. In this child class, I want to implement some processing methods to filter out certain row or columns for example.
More importantly, I also want these methods to modify the attributes in a "inplace" manner, without needing to return a copy (i.e. without `return self`). However, when I remove the `return self` in the methods, the instances of the class are not modified. More precisely, the `self` is modified inside the function, but the instance of the class remains unchanged.

### Code example:

Imagine the following example with class A inherited from `anndata.AnnData`. The class A has one method called `remove_last_row()` that removes the last row (i.e. obs) of the instance of the class A.

```
import anndata
import numpy as np

class A(anndata.AnnData): 
    
    def __init__(self, adata, data_type=None): 
        """
        Initition method 
        
        Parameters: 
        -----------
        adata: anndata.AnnData, 
            The Anndata object
        """
        super().__init__(adata)
        
    def remove_last_row(self): 
        """
        Remove the last row of the anndata object
        """
        
        print("--> In A.remove_last_row() method:")
        print("before filtering: number rows = ", self.X.shape[0])
        
        # get the row index to keep (i.e. the index of the obs without the last one)
        index_to_keep = self.obs[:-1].values.astype(int)
        # Keep only those index: 
        self = self[index_to_keep, :]
        
        print("after filtering: number rows = ", self.X.shape[0])
        print("<-- exit A.remove_last_row() method.")
```

The problem when using the `remove_last_row()` method is that the row of the instance (self) is removed inside the function but it does not modify the instance of the class.
See the example bellow:

```
# Create an AnnData object: 
adata = anndata.AnnData(np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]))
    
# Create object A that is inherited from AnnData
obj_A = A(adata = adata)
    
# Test remove_last_row method
obj_A.remove_last_row()

print()
print("obj_A.X attribute = \n", obj_A.X)
```

Which results in:

> --> In A.remove_last_row() method:
> before filtering: number rows =  3
> after filtering: number rows =  2
> <-- exit A.remove_last_row() method.
>
> obj_A.X attribute =
> [[0. 0. 0.]
> [1. 1. 1.]
> [2. 2. 2.]]

We see that in the `remove_last_row()` method, the last row is removed in `self` inside the function. However, the `obj_A` (instance of class A) is not modified by this method. How can I solve this without adding the `return self`.

---

### Additional information:

- Python version=3.6.12
- numpy version=1.19.1
- anndata version=0.7.4
- scanpy version=1.6.0

I have also tested a method that I have called `addition()` which adds a certain value to every element of the array `X`. With this method, I do not suffer from this problem.

If the method `addition()` is in the class A:

```
   def addition(self, x=1): 
        """
        Add a value of x for each element in the X numpy array in the AnnData object
        
        Parameters: 
        -----------
        x: float,
            The value added to every element 
        """
        self.X += x
```

We can test:

```
# Create an AnnData object: 
adata = anndata.AnnData(np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]))

# Create object A that is inherited from AnnData
print("Before addition")
obj_A = A(adata = adata)
print("obj_A.X attribute = \n", obj_A.X)

# Test the addition method
print()
obj_A.addition(x=1)
print()
print("After addition")
print("obj_A.X attribute = \n", obj_A.X)
```

The results are:

> Before addition
> obj_A.X attribute =
> [[0. 0. 0.]
> [1. 1. 1.]
> [2. 2. 2.]]
>
> After addition
> obj_A.X attribute =
> [[1. 1. 1.]
> [2. 2. 2.]
> [3. 3. 3.]]

As you can see the `addition()` method worked. It was able to modify the instance of the class.

Comment: btw `self = ...` is usually pointless in a method.

Comment: `self.X` is an array type that has probably `+=` overriden with implementing a method like `_iadd__` or `__add__`. `self` is an instance of `AnnData` (and maybe thus an array?), but the assignment operator `=` is not overriden. If you'll do `self = ...` you'll just shadow the real `self` instance, and the local `self` will go out of scope as soon as the method terminates. You'll have to find some different way to alter `self`. You could try something like `del self[inds]` to remove indices that you don't like, this requires `AnnData` or one of its parents to have `__del__` implemented.

Comment: According to https://github.com/theislab/anndata/blob/58886f09b2e387c6389a2de20ed0bc7d20d1b843/anndata/_core/anndata.py#L145-L2010`__delitem__` is implemented and you should be able to do so.

Comment: Thanks to your comments I was able to find a solution. 
I modified the `remove_last_row()` method in class A to delete the rows using the [`_inplace_subset_obs`](https://github.com/theislab/anndata/blob/master/anndata/_core/anndata.py) method (Same as `adata = adata[index, :]`, but inplace.)


Note that I didn't use the common `del` method of the AnnData due to some common error ([link](https://github.com/theislab/anndata/issues/73)).